# oracle log on denied in 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, oracle12c

I am getting this error message while logging on to database. I have uploaded the screenshot also. Please tell me what can be the issue?[image]

Comment: Is this a dev day image? You were already logged in as sysdba when you attempted to connect to system.

Comment: did n't get u frnd, i started tns listener service , listener i have set username system and password system, still showing the error

Comment: Is this a local database or a hosted one somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you have created your database along with **CREATE AS PLUGGABLE DATABASE** option. Thus, Oracle doesn't know of the database you actually want to connect to.

Include the required and correct service_name/database_name to connect to the CDB/PDB respectively.

In your case, the **ORACLE_SID** might be pointing to the CDB, thus you successfully connected via `/ as sysdba`. Try with the following -

`conn system@database_name/password`

Make sure you have edited the `tnsnames.ora` to add the required details post installation.

**UPDATE** OP mentioned in the comment that he created with the PDB option.

If you want to connect to the **CDB/PDB**, please explicitly mention the **container/pluggable database name**. Please read [**Oracle 12c Post Installation Mandatory Steps**](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/10/01/mandatory-steps-for-12c-installation/).

Comment: ya create as pluggable database is ticked while installing the database, but how to connect to user system?

Comment: now getting error ORA-12154 : TNS could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: So you want to connect to the pluggable database or the container database? I would insist, have a look at the I posted in the answer.

Comment: As I said, make sure you have added the required details in your tnsnames.ora file. Better go through the link.

Comment: ok what is d big difference between these two? which one will be better?

Comment: What do you mean by *which one will be better*??? It is you and only you who is at the requirement end and knows better what is needed. I provided you a solution based on my experience with post 12c installation requirements. You MUST elucidate what you need more.

Comment: Once again, did you at least look at the link I provided? `tnsnames.ora` file resides locally in your `ORACLE_HOME/network/admin`. Would you care to post your OS???????

Answer (score 1):

I believe the default `SYSTEM` password is <strike>manager</strike> `password`, not system.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing to the listener, honestly.

Comment: Could you please prove how do you claim about the default password?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTDBI/startrdb.htm#NTDBI2843  I was not correct. :)

Comment: @mmmmmpie Your edit made it incorrect. Actually, if you do not provide the password for `SYSTEM` during installation, then it defaults to `manager`.  You should always change it at first logon. The documentation  link you pointed to, is just an example of providing a password, that doesn't mean the password itself is `password`.